# Job for mysqld.service failed in Centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos7

**OS**:Centos 7 Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64

**MySQL**: `mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm`

I installed MySQL server through `yum`. When I run `systemctl start mysqld` I get the following error

*Job for mysqld.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysqld.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.*

**systemctl status mysqld.service**

```
MySQL Server Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled) 
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2015-12-06 03:14:54 GMT;
4min 7s ago Process: 6992 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
--daemonize $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Process: 6971 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited,
status=0/SUCCESS) 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server. 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit  mysqld.service entered failed state. 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart. 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Server... 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...   
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start. 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server. 
Dec 06 03:14:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state. The journal command reads Failed to start MySQL Server
```

Any ideas what else I should be looking at?

Comment: What version of `gnutls` do you have (`yum list installed gnutls `)?

Comment: Can u please reformat the error lines being thrown by the service start command for readability . Also please post the last few lines from mysql error log.

Comment: I did it already. Unfortunatelly formatted code is not helpful anyway. Could you look at mysqld logs for more details?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check below things to fix the issue

1. Check the permission of mysql data dir using below command. The ownership should be `mysql:mysql` and the directory permission should be `700`

   ```
   ls -ld /var/lib/mysql/
   ```
2. Check the permission of databases inside mysql data dir using below command. The ownership should be mysql:mysql for all the files inside that directory

   ```
   ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/
   ```
3. Check the listening network tcp ports using below command

   ```
   netstat -ntlp
   ```
4. Check the mysql log files for any error using below command.

   ```
   cat /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
   ```
5. Try to start mysql using below command

   ```
   mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cf
   ```

Comment: But what should be the permissions? drwx------ will do? That's what it is.

Comment: What should be the permission ?

Comment: The problem in my case was that I had deleted everything in `/var/log` sometime back to save space, and thus it did not contain the folder `/var/log/mysql` and `mysqld` couldn't create one because it did not have root permissions. **Fixed it** by creating one, assigning mysql:mysql as the owner and then setting permission to 700.

Comment: @forumulator, If you start mysql with the method mentioned in point no 5, you will get to know what is the error. Like in your case mysql will complain about the missing log directory.

Answer (score -4):

For me the above answer did not help, so here is my solution.

Find out open mysqld process

`ps -ef | grep mysqld`

And kill all those process

`pkill -9 mysqld`

Finally start it the same by using

`systemctl start mariadb`

Issue resolved....