# MySQL 5.7.27 can’t start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just installed MySQL 5.7.23 on Centos 7. As soon as I do systemctl start mysqld gives me an error.  Making systemctl status mysqld returns:

```
●�mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
���Active: failed�(Result: start-limit) since Tue 2019-08-27 02:55:20 CEST; 11min ago
�����Docs: man:mysqld(8)
  ���������http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
��Process: 11299 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
��Process: 11281 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Aug 27 02:55:20 server0-centos7 systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Comment: Is there any more info in the logs in `/var/log`?

Answer (score 1):

There can be various reasons for this issue.

1. Required folder permissions may not be there.

Please find the answer related to folder permission here.

[Job for mysqld.service failed in Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113689/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-in-centos-7)

2. You may have less RAM free with the MySQL service stopped, so as soon as you run:

**systemctl start mysqld**

MySQL is attempting to utilize more than what’s available and since it’s unable to do so, it fails.

For database-driven websites, I recommend at least 1GB of RAM minimum. if you still want to run with less MB of RAM then I’d recommend NGINX over Apache.